# replace div id and text inside another div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Background:
I am inserting two calendars on a page, which are both generated on the back end (Business Catalyst) so I have no control over the calendars other than what events it should contain.  The issue I have is that both calendars have the same DIV ID.

What I want to achieve:
After the page loads, I want to use javascript to change (1) the DIV ID of the **second calendar** and (2) the reference to the same ID inside the script of the calendar.

This is the html containing the two calendars (with bulk removed)

```
<div id="nav-8-1-default-hor-left--1" role="tabpanel">
    <h2>Social Calendar</h2>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar starts here -->
    <div id="calendar-container">
        <!-- Generated Calendar here-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cal = document.getElementById('calendar-container');
        // rest of calendar script here
    </script>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar ends here -->
</div>

<div id="nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2" role="tabpanel">
    <h2>Workshop Calendar</h2>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar starts here -->
    <div id="calendar-container">
        <!-- Generated Calendar here-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cal = document.getElementById('calendar-container');
        // rest of calendar script here
    </script>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar ends here -->
</div>
```

This is the script I tried, but it has no effect:

```
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    //replace ID of second calendar and ref to its id in script
    $('#nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2').find('#calendar-container').attr("id", "#calendar-container2");
    $('#nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2').find('calendar-container').replace('calendar-container', 'calendar-container2');
});
```

I am a newbie with javascript/jquery, so please explain your answer

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you are going to do this.  Because this isn't a simple swap.  Both of these divs are including a script tag in them that references that id.  That script will already have been evaluated by the time the page has loaded.  I'm not sure how you could destroy that logic from the browser memory.  Even then, you'd have to do something funky like grab the script content, modify it, and then append a new script to the page or do an eval on it, which is just nasty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope there is no other element with same string in the 2nd calendar.

I have done following.

I take entire html of `<div id="nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2" role="tabpanel">` and store it in a variable `x` and then I replace 'calendar-container' with 'calendar-container2' using string.replace method and get the new string. And then I applied back this string as html of `<div id="nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2" role="tabpanel">`.(I replace 'calendar-container' with 'calendar-container2' at all place in '' div)

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    var x=$('#nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2').html();
    
    x=x.replace(/calendar-container/g,'calendar-container2');
    $('#nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2').html(x);
    console.log($('#nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2').html());
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-8-1-default-hor-left--1" role="tabpanel">
    <h2>Social Calendar</h2>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar starts here -->
    <div id="calendar-container">
        <!-- Generated Calendar here-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cal = document.getElementById('calendar-container');
        // rest of calendar script here
    </script>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar ends here -->
</div>

<div id="nav-8-1-default-hor-left--2" role="tabpanel">
    <h2>Workshop Calendar</h2>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar starts here -->
    <div id="calendar-container">
        <!-- Generated Calendar here-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cal = document.getElementById('calendar-container');
        // rest of calendar script here
    </script>
    <!-- backend inserted calendar ends here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I applied your script to my page.  The output to the console shows that the correct changes occurred, but the page source itself did not update - any ideas?

Comment: try to check using 'inspect element'(right click),let me know if that's also not changed(as page source mostly not shows the apply changes)

Comment: you were correct - inspecting element actually showed the changes and the calendars navigation works correctly.

Comment: sorry I was a bit too quick with my response - it seems something interesting happend to the updated html.

Comment: this is the original structure:<div id=nav... >, <h2>.., <div id=calendar-container>, <div class=select month year>
After the update the structure has added div with original id like this:
<div id=nav... >, <h2>.., <div id=calendar-container2>,<div id=calendar-container>, <div class=select month year>
Anyway, not sure how this affects the script, but will keep the answer

Comment: @Marius not sure how it is happening, if you could share link(if you want) or something(create demo and reflact same thing), then I can check.

Comment: You can view a sample page here [link](https://goldtemplate.businesscatalyst.com/test/bc-dualcal-test.html)
When you open the page and look at 2nd calendar it will look fine, but then go and change to a diffent month and you will see the inserted div below the calendar-container2 div

Comment: @Marius I debug your code, and it's work perfectly when you are changing it(no additional div is added), but when entire script runs div is added so its look like you are inserting that div from somewhere else again into `container-calender2`(I can't able to find from where you are inserting that in this much time,sorry for that)

Comment: the calendars incl their scripts are generated by Business Catalyst.  My guess is that the month/year change is calling BC to update the data in the calendar, so if it cannot find the original div id, it inserts a new one - Don't worry any further, I am planning to use a 3rd party calendar plugin like fullCalendar.js - thanks you for all your input it was very valuable.